# Sharing folders on LAN with a DMZ computer on same tier (in DMZ)

Tags: lan, shared-folders, dmz

This is my current setup, tiers in order;

1. Modem
2. Linksys wireless router
3. D-Link wired router - wired desktop 1 - wireless laptop
4. Wired DMZ desktop 2

Modem is connected to the linksys wireless router, wireless router has the D-Link wired router, a desktop and a laptop connected to it. the wired router has a desktop connected to it using DMZ. so in theory, the desktop should appear in tier 3 with the other computers, still hidden behind the Linksys firewall.

My problem is that I want to create a shared folder on the DMZ desktop and access it from the laptop, but the DMZ desktop isn't visible on the network...anywhere, and the DMZ desktop doesn't see anything else on the network either, other than the D-Link router.

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the server-computer by it's IP address.  For example, if the machine you wish to share folders from is at 10.1.1.33, you would access it as:  \10.1.1.33\

Comment: just tried that, unfortunately didnt work... did however notice something else though, the wired router providing the dns (dlink) is inacessable from my laptop aswell... so i guess i might look around settings on the dlink from my desktop and see if theres anything noticable goin on. 
thanks for the reply :)

Comment: There may be some firewall settings in the DLink router that are set to block everything aggressively.  If you can, try to get a close look at your DLink router's routing and firewalling settings.